# How can I show multiple videos with React Native Video in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

How can I show multiple videos with the React Native Video component of React Native?

Here is the [React Native Video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) GitHub repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store videos in **Array** like you stored array in `var array` and use **[Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)** and pass data as the array you stored in `array` variable, then render the Flat list items as video tag.

The flat list will show all the videos in a list.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

const Videos = [
  {
    Videourl: 'url1',
  },
  {
    Videourl: 'url2',
  },
  {
    Videourl: 'url3',
  },
];


export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
      <Video source={item.Videourl}  
   ref={(ref) => {
     this.player = ref
   }}                                      
   onBuffer={this.onBuffer}               
   onError={this.videoError}               
   style={styles.backgroundVideo} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Comment: hey @AnujSharma when I try to implement the same, it is showing "loading an empty source", any idea why is that?

Comment: Hi @TRINACHAUDHURI  , i think there is some issue with your Array , the flatlist is getting Empty value I guess.